# Face set colors not showing in sculpt mode despite trying multiple things (2.91.0)

Tags: sculpting

Blender 2.91.0

Cannot see face set colors despite creating face sets, setting face sets, boxing face sets, drawing in face sets, making sure face set is being shown in viewport shading and overlays options.

I saw another stack question talking about modifiers being the issue. I have no modifiers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dynotopo mode prevents editing face sets. If face sets exist, they will be removed when  the mesh is sculpted while dynotopo is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It may be uncheck in overlay viewport.